# Problem with running open office from the command line

Tags: linux, openoffice, rpm

Yesterday I installed OpenOffice on my Linux server. But when I go to run it through the command line, it says command cannot be found. I've also tried other things like OOWriter, etc. Has anyone had this problem? Installation process went like below:

```
    root@aserver [OOO330_m20_native_packed-1_en-US.9567/RPMS]#
    rpm -i *.rpm 
        package openoffice.org-ure-1.7.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core01-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core02-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core03-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core04-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core05-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core06-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-core07-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-base-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-calc-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-draw-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-help-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-impress-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-math-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-res-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-writer-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-base-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-calc-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-draw-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-images-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-impress-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-math-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-writer-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package jre-1.6.0_22-fcs.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-binfilter-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-en-US-binfilter-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-gnome-integration-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-graphicfilter-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-javafilter-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-kde-integration-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-onlineupdate-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-ooofonts-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-oooimprovement-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-ooolinguistic-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-pyuno-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-testtool-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package ooobasis3.3-xsltfilter-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-base-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-calc-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-dict-en-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-dict-es-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-dict-fr-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-draw-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-en-US-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-impress-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-math-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
        package openoffice.org3-writer-3.3.0-9567.i586 is already installed
    root@aserver [OOO330_m20_native_p

acked-1_en-US.9567/RPMS]# soffice
bash: soffice: command not found
```

Comment: rpm -ql openoffice.org3-3.3.0-9567.i586 or so..

Answer (score 0):

The binary name is `ooffice`, not `soffice`:

```
$ ooffice
```

Answer (score 0):

It's soffice but you need to be in the correct path or set your environment point to it. The default install location is `/opt/openoffice.org3`